# How to reload the route after using Back button from the browser?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

The problem I'm having here is the list in the footer of the HOME route is no longer presented when clicked the Back button from the browser.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url : '/product',
    views : {
        "main" : {
            templateUrl : '/product.html'
        },
        "footer" : {
            template : '<footer show-list="true"></footer>'
        }   
    }
});
$stateProvider.state('checkout', {
    url : '/checkout',
    views : {
        "mainContent" : {
        templateUrl : '/checkout.html'
        },
        "footer" : {
            template : '<footer show-list="false"></footer>'
        }   
    },
});
```

So far is fine by starting with the HOME page and there is a drop down list in the footer view.  Then it routes to the checkout page.  Now when click the Back button in the browser to go back to the HOME page, the drop down list is no longer there unless I have to click Refresh to hard reload the page.

How can I reload the HOME route so it can load the list?  The show-list is true but nothing happens, why?

Comment: Store your drop down list data in a service so that it's available even upon route changes. When the route changes, you would just restore the drop down list from the service without making a call to your server.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in plunker? I don't see any issue with the code..

Comment: Thanks but my drop-down list is already in the service.  So when the show-list is true, the drop down list will populated with the data.  The issue is even the show-list is true after the Back button, the drop down list is still not visible.  Now if I do the hard reload using Refresh button then the drop down list is there.

Comment: The code is working fine but I want to know if I can perhaps add route.reload() or something when using Back button is detected?

Comment: @J.TrLu You should have to reload anything if you already have the list, that is the advantage of using a framework like angular. Your problem is probably in the home controller or home html, can you post those?